# how do i parse my json data in to the grouped tablevie based on data size set cell height?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

my json data is

```
{
    0 = "sriram";
    1 = "sriram@gmail.com";
    2 = y;
    3 = "A/2, Vraj vihar -2,
 \nOpp. Palashial Bunglows,
 \nNear star India Bazaar,
 \nsatellite,
  \njodhpur.";
    4 = "";
    5 = 1234657890;
    active = y;
    address = "A/2, Vraj vihar -2,
   \nOpp. Palashial Bunglows,
  \nNear star India Bazaar,
  \nsatellite,
  \njodhpur, Ahmadabad.";
    email = "sriram@gmail.com";
    full name = "sriram";
    phone = 1234657890;
    phone2 = "";
}
```

am parse this data into grouped table view.i have one problem cell showing limited data
but i need based on data set the cell height. for example one cell have 1 line another 30 lines based on data automatically set the cell size

please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
UITableViewCell *theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *text = theCell.textLabel.text;
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);
return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

Using the above code you could specify the height of each row according to the text in it.

Comment: UITableViewCell *theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; here am getting error application crash